# Placing a Method with Eval parameter into a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I would like to change the forecolor of a field in a datalist using the technique below.  But I'm not sure how to call a method, in combination with Eval.

This code creates the error: The best overloaded method match for '_Default.RowColor(string)' has some invalid arguments

**ASPX**

```
<ItemTemplate>
<a href='<%# "http://cc.lookup.aspx?Quotenum=" + Eval("quote") %>'>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor='<%# RowColor(Eval("status")) %>' Text='<%# Bind("quote") %>'></asp:Label>
    </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**C#**

```
public System.Drawing.Color RowColor(string rowType)
{
    System.Drawing.Color retval = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    if (rowType == "Quote") retval = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast or convert it to string. Because your `public System.Drawing.Color RowColor(string rowType)` method takes `string` type argument.

Try this.

```
 ForeColor='<%# RowColor(Eval("status").ToString()) %>'
```

or

```
ForeColor='<%# RowColor((string) Eval("status")) %>'
```

Comment: We meet again... for almost exactly the same question :)

Comment: Didn't realize I was so close.  Still working on the same DataGrid. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: Yes but a little mistake create problem for you. Never mind it happens some time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `Eval("Status")` to a string.

```
'<%# RowColor(Eval("Status").ToString()) %>'
```

Comment: Yes and question is almost same +1 for you.